# ValueError: not enough values to pack (expected 2, got 1) syntax error

Tags: python-2.x

Hello I am taking an example from learn python the hard way and working to understand python. I have already caught one error in the book and realized you need () to print out strings. So maybe there could be some more mistakes in the syntax. when I ran this file I received an error that said

ValueError: not enough values to pack (expected 2, got 1) syntax error. And another general syntax error. So I can't set prompt to raw_input.

```
rom sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '>'


print ("Hi %s, I'm the $s script.") % user_name, script
print ("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")
print ("Do you like %s?") % user_name  
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print ("Where do you live %s") % user_name
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print """
(Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
 And you have a %r computer. Nice)
 """& (likes, lives, computer)
```

Comment: When posting code or error messages, please **copy-paste** code from a file you have actually run, and **copy-paste** error messages from actual error output. It looks like you've misrepresented both your code and your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in the code example?  `$s` instead of `%s` in the format string?

I suspect that your actual code has this:

```
print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script.") % user_name, script
```

And you meant to write this:

```
print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script)
```

That is, print a single string which is the result of applying the format string to two arguments.